# Using variable value from one Shiny module in another module

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have three modules:

- The first module creates a `numericInput` with value equal to 1.
- The second module creates a `textInput` that is created with `renderUI` in the server function. The value is equal to the value of the first module + 1.
- The third module should do the same as the second module, but with the value equal to the value of the second module + 1.

The choice for `textInput` and `renderUI` in the second and third module is deliberate. The code works without the third module, but throws the following error when the third module is included: `Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Below is the minimal example code. Help would be much appreciated!

**first_module.R**

```
#Define ui
first_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(numericInput(
    inputId = ns("first_input"),
    label = "First input:",
    value = 1
  ))
}

#Define server logic
first_module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(input)
}
```

**second_module.R**

```
#Define ui
second_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("second_input")))
}

#Define server logic
second_module_server <- function(input, output, session, first_module_res) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observe({
      second_input <- first_module_res$first_input + 1
      output$second_input <- renderUI({
        disabled(textInput(
          inputId = ns("second_input"),
          label = "Second input:",
          value = second_input
        ))
      })
    })
    return(reactive({second_input}))
  }
```

**third_module.R**

```
#Define ui
third_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("third_input")))
}

#Define server logic
third_module_server <- function(input, output, session, second_module_res) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observe({
      third_input <- second_module_res$second_input + 1
      output$third_input <- renderUI({
        disabled(textInput(
          inputId = ns("third_input"),
          label = "Third input:",
          value = third_input
        ))
      })
    })
  }
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Demo"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            first_module_ui("first")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            second_module_ui("second"),
            third_module_ui("third")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    callModule(first_module_server, "first")
    first_module_res <- callModule(first_module_server, "first")
    
    callModule(second_module_server, "second", first_module_res)
    second_module_res <- callModule(second_module_server, "second", first_module_res)
    
    callModule(third_module_server, "third", second_module_res)
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

- you don't need `observe`, you can use `reactive` instead because your interest is in the return value (see [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html))
- you should make the calculated values to reactives
- you don't need to call a module twice

Your code didn't work because of how you return the value from the module server function. From the first module, you return the complete `input` This allows you in the second module to access the values from the `input` of the first module as you would access it without any modules in the `server` function from the main app. This means that you don't need brackets to evaluate the reactive, you can just do `first_module_res$first_input` as you would do with `input$first_input`.

However, the second module doesn't return `input`, but a reactive created by you (via `reactive({})` in the return value). This now becomes the value that is inputted into the third module and needs to be evaluated there with brackets: `second_module_res()`. Also note that you directly evaluate the reactive, because it is the only returned value (and not the complete `input` of the second module).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#Define ui
first_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(numericInput(
    inputId = ns("first_input"),
    label = "First input:",
    value = 1
  ))
}

#Define server logic
first_module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(input)
}

#Define ui
second_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("second_input")))
}

#Define server logic
second_module_server <- function(input, output, session, first_module_res) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  second_input <- reactive({
    first_module_res$first_input + 1
  })
  
    output$second_input <- renderUI({
      disabled(textInput(
        inputId = ns("second_input"),
        label = "Second input:",
        value = second_input()
      ))
    })
  return(reactive({second_input()}))
}

#Define ui
third_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("third_input")))
}

#Define server logic
third_module_server <- function(input, output, session, second_module_res) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  third_input <- reactive({
    second_module_res() + 1
  })
  
    output$third_input <- renderUI({
      disabled(textInput(
        inputId = ns("third_input"),
        label = "Third input:",
        value = third_input()
      ))
    })
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Demo"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      first_module_ui("first")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      second_module_ui("second"),
      third_module_ui("third")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  first_module_res <- callModule(first_module_server, "first")
  
  second_module_res <- callModule(second_module_server, "second", first_module_res)
  
  callModule(third_module_server, "third", second_module_res)
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

### Edit

You can return a list from a module with several reactives:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#Define ui
first_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(numericInput(
    inputId = ns("first_input"),
    label = "First input:",
    value = 1
  ))
}

#Define server logic
first_module_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(input)
}

#Define ui
second_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("second_input")),
          numericInput(
            inputId = ns("additional_input"),
            label = "Additional input",
            value = 5
          ))
}

#Define server logic
second_module_server <- function(input, output, session, first_module_res) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  second_input <- reactive({
    first_module_res$first_input + 1
  })
  
  output$second_input <- renderUI({
    disabled(textInput(
      inputId = ns("second_input"),
      label = "Second input:",
      value = second_input()
    ))
  })
  return(list(
    second_input = reactive({second_input()}),
    additional_input = reactive({input$additional_input})
  ))
}

#Define ui
third_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(uiOutput(outputId = ns("third_input")),
          verbatimTextOutput(outputId = ns("fourth_output")))
}

#Define server logic
third_module_server <- function(input, output, session, second_module_res) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  third_input <- reactive({
    second_module_res$second_input() + 1
  })
  
  output$third_input <- renderUI({
    disabled(textInput(
      inputId = ns("third_input"),
      label = "Third input:",
      value = third_input()
    ))
  })
  
  output$fourth_output <- renderPrint({
    second_module_res$additional_input()
  })
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Demo"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      first_module_ui("first")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      second_module_ui("second"),
      third_module_ui("third")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  first_module_res <- callModule(first_module_server, "first")
  
  second_module_res <- callModule(second_module_server, "second", first_module_res)
  
  callModule(third_module_server, "third", second_module_res)
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @starja ! Not just for the revised code, but also for elaborating. A follow-up questions if you don't mind (to expand my understanding): If there was another `textInput` rendered in the second module, how could that be used in the third module? Would be even more grateful if you could extend the code to illustrate this.

Comment: @Rishi just return a list of reactives, see my edit